# Latex Numbered Hanging \paragraph

Tags: latex, indentation, pdflatex, paragraph

I am trying to write a document which uses seperate numbers for sections and paragraphs.
I would like each \paragraph to have a hanging indent such that the first word of the second line, aligns with the first word of the first line.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}

% Heading/Subheading counter
\newcounter{subsubsection}[subsubsection]
\newcounter{param} % Paragraph counter
\newcommand{\N}{%
   \noindent\refstepcounter{parnum}%
    \makebox[\parindent][l]{\arabic{parnum}.}}
\newcommand\YUGE{\fontsize{60}{100}\selectfont}

% Paragraph style
\renewcommand\thesubsubsubsection{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{subsubsubsection}}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\thesubsubsubsection.\arabic{paragraph}} 
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{5}{\z@}%
    {1em} {-1em} {\normalsize\normalfont}}
\def\toclevel@subsubsubsection{4}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{5}
\def\l@subsubsubsection{\@dottedtocline{4}{7em}{4em}}
\def\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{10em}{5em}}
\makeatother
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\section{Scope}  
    \pagestyle{style1}
    \paragraph*{\N} The Scope of this document should number each paragraph sequentially:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item [a.] List item 1,
        \item [b.] List item 2, and
        \item [...] ...
        \item [n.] List item n.
    \end{itemize}
    \paragraph*{\N} Second paragraph with numbering
    
    \subsection{Intro}
    \paragraph*{\N} This is the intro.
    \paragraph*{\N} Intro cont.
    
    \subsubsection{related docs}
    \paragraph*{\N} Here is a list of the related docs
    \begin{itemize}
        \item [a.] ...
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

This is a picture of what it looks like currently.
[image: What the text looks like currently]
Here is a quick example in word as to how I want the paragraphs to work (disregard the different numbering and font type. I am only concerned with the hanging indent).
[image: What I want the text to look like]

Comment: Instead of changing the indent of the following text lines, I suggest to increase the margin and move the section/paragraph numbering into the margin e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55197/how-can-i-number-paragraphs-and-sections-in-the-margin or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866079/latex-typesetting-chapter-and-section-number-in-margin

Comment: Thanks,
That option works perfect for what I want. The only issue is now numbering the paragraphs (which doesn't want to work for some reason) and aligning them in the margin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer; You need to use the following packages

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
```

Then you need to set the counter depth for the document to 5 and define a new counter. Which means you will be countering every; chapter, section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph and subparagraph.

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\newcounter{para}
\newcommand{\N}{\noindent\refstepcounter{para}\makebox[\parindent][l]{\arabic{para}.}}
```

Now you can set up the format for each of the sections/subsections/paragraphs/etc

```
\newlength\titleindent
\setlength\titleindent{1.25cm}
\pretocmd{\paragraph}{\stepcounter{subsubsection}}{}{}

\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\llap{\parbox{\titleindent}{\thesection\hfill}}}{0em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\llap{\parbox{\titleindent}{\thesubsection\hfill}}}{0em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\llap{\parbox{\titleindent}{\thesubsubsection}}}{0em}{}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize}{\llap{\parbox{\titleindent}{\N\hfill}}}{0em}{}

\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{2ex plus 1ex minus 0.2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{2ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0ex plus 0ex}
```

I did not use the subparagraph option to I changed the commands such that the numbering of paragraphs is the same level as subsubsections. This means a subsubsection might be numbered 1.2.1 if you have two paragraphs though the next subsubsection will be 1.2.4 is an issue I have yet to solve.
The below is the original commands:

```
\pretocmd{\paragraph}{\stepcounter{subsection}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\subparagraph}{\stepcounter{subsubsection}}{}{}
```

Importantly when writing your code, you need to use the following syntax at the beginning of each paragraph:

```
\paragraph{} Some text
```

Here is an example

```
\begin{document}
\section{title}
\subsection{Intro}
    \paragraph{} The Scope of this document should number each paragraph sequentially:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item [a.] List item 1,
        \item [b.] List item 2, and
        \item [...] ...
        \item [n.] List item n.
    \end{itemize}
    \paragraph{} Second paragraph with numbering, this is sample text to explain the 
    hanging indent format, which should align with the second line of this paragraph 
    with the first line.

\subsection{Intro}
    \paragraph{}This is the intro, this is sample text to explain the hanging indent 
    format, which should align with the second line of this paragraph with the first 
    line.
    \paragraph{} Intro cont, this is sample text to explain the hanging indent format, 
    which should align with the second line of this paragraph with the first line.

    \subsubsection{related docs}
        \paragraph{} Here is a list of the related docs
        \begin{itemize}
            \item [a.] ...
         \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

This is what it looks like now
[image]